# Join Two tables having different number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, ssis, business-intelligence

I have a scenario like this in ssis - I have got two different inputs, out of which one is coming from a lookup nomatch output. The other input is actually a derived column that is takn from a single row single column result in an oledb source using sql query. The problem is that I need to join these two inputs and make it a single dataset to further push the data to the crm destination(Cozyroc).

I know union all just cant do the work since it works on union of rows from different datasets.

Also merge and merge join cannot be used since a common id or key need to be given inorder to join the two datasets, and i have got no such thing.

For example, my first dataset looks like:

```
usinessid          userid      name
---------          ------      ----
ret678             435         john
dfgt67             213         sam
```

and my second dataset is like:

```
systemid
------------------------
6666-777-kjtyr-213t-ytui
```

which is extracted using a single column single row query using the oledb source - sql command.

Is there a way to combine these two dataset so that the end result will be something like:

```
businessid         userid           name          systemid
----------         ------           ----          ------------------------
ret678             435              john          6666-777-kjtyr-213t-ytui 
dfgt67             213              sam           6666-777-kjtyr-213t-ytui
```

I want to do this without using a variable or using a derived column and hardcoding the systemid value.

Pardon my editing...

Any further inputs on this issue will be really helpful.

Comment: Could you help your verbal description with an example? What do the two inputs look like and what output would you like to get out of them?

Comment: I think a script component (type transformation) will be suitable for the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine the two datasets the way you've shown, you could use a simple cross join:

```
SELECT
  t1.businessid,
  t1.userid,
  t1.name,
  t2.systemid
FROM
  table1 t1
CROSS JOIN
  table2 t2
;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, this seems to be the way to do this. However, SSIS does not have a feature of using cross join directly. Is there any way to do this in SSIS..

Comment: Another way to produce a cross product of two tables would be to do `SELECT ... FROM table1 t1, table2 t2`. Does SSIS support something like that?

Comment: Ok. I got it. For using cross joins in SSIS, there is no direct way. Indirectly, you can create a derived column like 'join_key' for each data set and assigning them the value 1. Then use sort transformation on both derived column outputs and select 'join_key' field to sort. Finally, doing a full outer join on the requierd fields can produce a cross join result..

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for sharing this workaround, I think I may need to keep it in mind for the future. By the way, do you think it has to be a full outer join? Would SSIS permit an inner join in that situation? I do believe it should work as well, and it might also turn out more efficient, although that would still need to be tested before being pronounced true.

Comment: Also, for the benefit of other visitors, I do believe it would be a better idea if you posted your solution as your own answer (and accepted it once permitted). After all, although my solution seems logical, it doesn't really work in SSIS, does it? I mean, thanks for accepting my solution, it's just that it doesn't really solve the problems while *yours does*.

Comment: Yes. The solution will work with inner join as well, I tested it just now. By the way, I accepted your reply as answer since it rang the bell for using cross join in this scenario. I hadn't thought about it before....